# just answer the question

Tags: discussion

Would it be too much to ask for an answer to my question, rather than multiple posts of answers I didn't ask for!  I did not get an answer to my question about it being a foregone conclusion that the pork has gone bad?  Yes or No?

---

For reference: the original question [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/68555/has-it-gone-bad)

Comment: Repeatedly asking a question isn't going to get your question answered. It is our site's policy that, if an existing question answers a new one, it is closed as a duplicate. The answer you need is there, there's no need to keep asking the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long can cooked food be safely stored at room/warm temperature?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/how-long-can-cooked-food-be-safely-stored-at-room-warm-temperature)

Comment: Yes. And note that we expect different behaviour from all our users. Start with the [tour] and the [help], especially our [be nice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a follow-up rom a disgrunteled user, not a question.

Comment: And frankly, expecting us to answer a question as vague ast the original (how long has it been standing around, how does it smell...) is ridiculous. If in doubt, throw it out. We can't confirm what we can't see, touch or smell. Therefore, only the generic post on food safety remains.

Comment: Seasoned Advice isn't a one-on-one question and answer service; it's a community. Did you take the time to read the other questions/answers you were referred to?

Answer (score 6):

Your question was answered, by closing it as a duplicate of a more general question. That question says that more than a few hours in the danger zone is unsafe, so there you go: your forgotten food is unsafe, assuming it was forgotten for at least a few hours.

I'm sorry this wasn't communicated clearly enough for you, but I'd appreciate it if you didn't give folks a hard time about it; closing questions as duplicates is part of how the site works.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, yes.

We are not a "service", but a comunity of cooking enthusiasts who ask and answer questions in our free time and without any compensation or similar.

Seasoned Advice, like all other Stack Exchange sites, strives to build a knowledge base of information, not answer the same question over and over again. The [original post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/68555/has-it-gone-bad) was vague at best, so the best answer we could give was referring you to the general safety guidelines for food safety - which makes the question a duplicate and thus it was consequently closed.

To be more precise: You did not describe how long the food was at room temperature or any other detail. Yes, "foaming" is probably a sign of spoilage, but you are there, we aren't and none of us can make an informed decision without more (way more!) details. That said, in the linked duplicate post, you will find the often-repeated:

**If in doubt, throw it out!**

If you don't agree with the rules of this comunity, you are probably not a good fit.

Comment: While this is correct this time, we would have closed it even if the actual temperature and time were given in the question, for the reasons I outlined in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed difficult to strike a balance between being welcome to beginners (who want very simple information) and interesting to more advanced cooks (who are bored by the too simple questions). As with any expert, if you show enthusiasm in learning about our area, we are likely to have the patience to answer your questions.

Food safety rules happen to be designed around simplicity. You don't need an expert to decide if it is safe or unsafe, you read the rules (which are very short and clear) and apply them to your case, period. So, from our point of view:

- if somebody comes to ask about the safety of food left out, this person probably did not know of these rules.
- if the person never learns the rules, we will be swamped in trivial and boring questions, generating lots of work for us. The person will have to ask us every time (which takes many minutes) instead of deciding it for themselves (which takes a few seconds), generating a lot of work for them. It is a lose-lose situation.
- if the person is presented with the rules and is not interested in learning them, this person appears to see us not in a mentor role (which many of us like having) but in the role of a free service providers (which many of us dislike having). Most people here resent answering the questions of askers not interested in learning (note that I'm not saying whether this is good or bad, just describing the situation).

So, what we do with trivial questions about food safety is to close them as a duplicate of a question describing the basic rules of food safety. Reading the answers to those questions once - even only the top answer - and applying them to the trivial situation is entirely sufficient to provide an answer, reduces our load of trivial questions *and* is useful for the asker (who is likely to encounter food outside of the refrigerator again in the future).

If your question is closed as a duplicate and you find that the answers don't fit your situation, you can always point that out and vote/flag for reopening. If enough high-reputation users or a moderator are convinced that you are correct, the question will get reopened and hopefully also gain answers.